# Update GCP asset labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

What is the most efficient way to update all assets labels per project?

I can list all project resources and their labels with `gcloud asset search-all-resources --project=SomeProject`. The command also returns the labels for those assets.

Is there something like `gcloud asset update-labels`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the service but, [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) (Google's definitive service documentation), shows a single [`list`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/assets) method.

I suspect (!?) that you will need to iterate over all your resource types and update instances of them using any (there may not be) update (`PATCH`) method that permits label changes for that resource type.

This seems like a reasonable request and you may wish to submit a feature request using Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud` does not seem to have a update-labels command.

You could try the Cloud Resource Manager API. For example, call the REST or Python API: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#update-labels

Comment: I have the path to vertex AI model, but I don't know how to modify labels.

Comment: After reading the document for a long time, I didn't find out how Python operates labels.

Comment: @lazy https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/cloudresourcemanager_v3.projects.html#patch